# Are the doublets in the tutorial dataset in Scanpy/ Seurat already filtered?

Tags: scrnaseq, transcriptome, 10x-genomics

I noticed the tutorials that Scanpy and Seurat use do not demonstrate doublet removal in their down stream analysis.
Is the dataset output of cellranger count already doublet removed or do I need to incorporate doublet removal before doing quality control etc?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: CellRanger [doesn't remove doublets](https://kb.10xgenomics.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001074271-Does-Cell-Ranger-automatically-exclude-doublets-). Also, there is no doublet remotion in the tutorials of Scanpy, if you want to apply doublet filtering you should use `sc.external.pp.scrublet()`. I'm not sure about Seurat.

Answer (score 2):

No in general cellranger does not remove doublets. You can apply a tool like [Scrublet](https://scanpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/scanpy.external.pp.scrublet.html) in scanpy or [Doubletfinder](https://github.com/chris-mcginnis-ucsf/DoubletFinder) in Seurat to infer doublets based on a mixed-transcriptional signal.

I say in general because cellranger does detect certain types of doublets in two contexts:

1. Multi-species experiments, e.g. the so-called [barnyard experiment](https://kb.10xgenomics.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001074271-Does-Cell-Ranger-automatically-exclude-doublets-), cellranger detects cross-species doublets
2. With [CellPlex](https://support.10xgenomics.com/single-cell-gene-expression/software/pipelines/latest/output/cellplex-metrics) sample multiplexing, cellranger detects cross-tag (cross-CMO) doublets